# Apple Aperture - Batch edit

Tags: photos, aperture

I'm just editing a time lapse video I shot and have to change the exposure on about 1000 files. Is there a was in Apple Aperture to batch edit files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In Aperture it's called lift and stamp. Apple have a video explaining how to do just that [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/VI178).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is make your edits to one photo, then save the adjustments (I think it's called save as preset in the menu), then select all your photos and apply your saved adjustments.